# MySQL select first 5 rows after query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql result (having many rows) that I will use later. For now, I only need to access (sum) the first 5 rows. The problem is that the rows were saved from the query using "AS", so now they can be accessed by using `$row['name']` . How can I select the first 5 rows without using the "name" for each of them?

Is there any way for doing like so:

PHP:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;++$i)
   echo $row[$i];
```

?

**EDIT**
Sorry, my question was wrong.
Actually: How can I use the same $result 2 times without loosing the values by fetching the array?

Comment: what's wrong with the `for($i=0;$i<5;++$i)` statement?

Comment: you can use LIMIT in mysql query to get only 5 rows instead of getting all rows and using only 5 of them.

Comment: @hydra, sorry, see my edit  @harry Because later on I'll need all the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you use for working with DB? PDO? MySQLi? MySQL extension?

If you use MySQL extension (`mysql_connect()`, `mysql_query()` etc), you can use [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) to move the internal row pointer of the MySQL result:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if ( mysql_num_rows($res) ) {
    // process first 5 lines
    for ( $n = 0; $n < 5; ++$n ) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        if ( $row === false ) {
            break;
        }
        // do something with $row
        // ...
    }
    // reset pointer
    mysql_data_seek($res, 0);
    // process all rows
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
        // do something with $row
        // ...
    }
}
mysql_free_result($res);
```

---

Another option would be to fetch all results into an array and then work with that array. I can't think of any benefit of holding MySQL resource opened.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult) ) {
   $result[$row['primaryKey']] = $row;   // index the $result according to any fieldValue(say primay key) so that you can access a single records without looping)
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

use $result as many times as you want

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql query as

select * from table_name_ravi limit 0,5

just use this

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix up things. `$row['name']` accesses the column of a row with the name **name** sou you should work on your fetch function your `while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {}`